# Test_train_split with stratify

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to split by dataframe (~188k rows) into train and test sample. The column ('FLAG') is my target variable containing a value of either 0 or 1.

Since there are only about 1300 'FLAG' with value 1, I want to do a stratified split to ensure there is a representative number of 1 values in both samples.

I tried to split using sklearn's train_test_split function:

```
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, stratify=df["FLAG"])
```

My problem is, that the resulting train and test sample have 177942, respectively 52 rows. I would have expected something like 150400 and 37600 rows.

My understanding from reading the documentation ([sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)) is that I have to provide my dataframe, the test_size and the column containing the target classes (i.e. 'FLAG' in my case).

Even a generic example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': np.random.rand(100000), 'b': np.random.rand(100000), 'c': 0})
df.loc[np.random.randint(0, 100000, 1000), 'c'] = 1
tr, ts = train_test_split(df, test_size=.2, stratify=df['c'])
print(tr.shape, ts.shape)
```

Returns: `(93105, 3) (38, 3)`

My list of imports:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
```

My python version: 3.7.0
Sklearn version: 0.20.3
Pandas version: 0.23.4

Comment: Very interesting. I ran some tests with a randomly constructed sample df and it seems to be working fine. You should post some sample data so we can reproduce your problem. My sample df: `df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': np.random.rand(100000), 'b': np.random.rand(100000), 'c': 0})`. Set about 1000 values to 1: `df.loc[np.random.randint(0, 100000, 1000), 'c'] = 1`, split the data: `tr, ts = train_test_split(df, test_size=.2, stratify=df['c'])`. checking the shapes: `tr.shape` Out: `(80000, 3)`, and the num of 1s: `tr.c.sum()` Out: `796` and for ts: 199. So there seems to be an issue with your data

Comment: @Scotty I tried the same test. Funny enough, my train_test_split does the same weird thing with your example. I.e. I'm getting (93105, 3) and (38, 3). Now I'm even more confused.

Comment: @tk78: what versions of python and packages do you use? Can you put all the imports before the generic code and re-execute (ex: maybe your train_test_split is redefined by some other package and it's not the one you think)

Comment: @vladmihaisima I added the information you requested. BTW: I'm just testing this very thing using a virtual environment.

Comment: @tk78 What is your sklean and pandas version? Looks like a bug...

Comment: @tk78: you can get the packages versions by doing: `import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)`

Comment: @vladmihaisima Sklearn version is 0.20.3, pandas version is 0.23.4

Comment: All imports are at the very top of the code, but the problem persists. I also check whether updating all the relevant packages resolves the issue. No luck. And I set up a virtual environment with pandas, sklearn and numpy and tested there. Also, no luck.

Comment: I have python 3.7.2, sklearn 0.20.3, pandas 0.24.2 and for me it works. Suggestions: try only the imports and the generic test code without any other code (not sure you already do that), try on another machine (for the remote possibility that the installation is affected in some way).

Comment: I tested on another machine. Same issue. I think I try reinstalling python next.

Comment: The problem is caused by an integer overflow. I have no clue why I seem to be the only one out there facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

My investigations showed that the issue is caused by an integer overflow. The issue is happening only on Python 3.7.x 32bit. The 64bit version works fine.

In the end I switched to 64bit Python to resolve the issue (I previously had to use 32bit version due to an unrelated Oracle package dependency).